# How can I add a disabled option when populating a select with Vue.js v-for

Tags: vuejs2

I would like to add a disabled option to a select that I have bound with v-for binding. The Vue docs on [select](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Select) suggests adding one but the example is using hard coded options.

I want to create a disabled 'Please select one' with v-for binding to force the user to pick a option rather than defaulting to a particular selection. I currently add a 'Please select one' option to the list I'm binding the select to and it shows up and works fine but I don't want the user to be able to choose it again.

How can I accomplish this when using v-for binding to a select?

```
//Contrived example of adding the default selection text
data.dashboardDefinitionList.splice(0, 0, { Id: 0, Name:"Select a Dashboard" });

<select id="dashboardSelectNew" v-model="formVariables.dashboardDefIndex" v-on:change="getDashboard">
       <option v-for="(dd, index) in dashboardDefinitionList"
       :value="dd.Id"
       :selected="formVariables.dashboardDefIndex == index">
          {{ dd.Name }}
        </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Exactly what value are you wanting out of the select? Your `v-model` indicates you want an array index but you're setting the `value` attribute to an `id` property

Comment: @Phil nice catch, leftovers from trying to resolve the issue at hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your disabled option first, then do the `v-for`.

```
<select id="dashboardSelectNew" v-model="formVariables.dashboardDefinition" @change="getDashboard">
  <option disabled value="">Please select one</option>
  <option v-for="dd in dashboardDefinitionList" :key="dd.id" :value="dd">
    {{ dd.Name }}
  </option>
</select>
```

Note that I've also attempted to clean up your model / value binding but you may not want or need it.

For the initial value, you would set it to an actual entry from your *list* instead of a specific index, eg

```js
this.formVariables.dashboardDefinition = this.dashboardDefinitionList[someIndex]
```

Comment: This straightened me out, I think you missed the fact that I wanted the 'Please select one' originally selected, thus I don't arbitrarily load the 'wrong' (first) entry. So to set the initial value I added 'selected' to the 'Please select one'  option. Also discovered that @change does not seem to work, I had to stick with v-on:change.

Comment: Finally hit me why @change doesn't work for me, I'm using .NET MVC .cshtml page. When using Razor need to double up the @'s

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this adding `disabled selected` to appear first and cannot be selected also good practice to put  `value="0"`  because you are using `id` in the value attribute

```
<select id="dashboardSelectNew" v-model="formVariables.dashboardDefIndex" v-on:change="getDashboard">
       <option value="0"  disabled selected> Please select one </option>

       <option v-for="(dd, index) in dashboardDefinitionList"
       :value="dd.Id"
       :selected="formVariables.dashboardDefIndex == index">
          {{ dd.Name }}
        </option>
</select>
```